# Extracting the total number of seconds from an interval data-type

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

When subtracting `timestamps` the return value is an `interval` data-type. Is there an elegant way to convert this value into the total number of (milli/micro) seconds in the interval, i.e. an integer.

The following would work, but it's not very pretty:

```
select abs( extract( second from interval_difference ) 
          + extract( minute from interval_difference ) * 60 
          + extract( hour from interval_difference ) * 60 * 60 
          + extract( day from interval_difference ) * 60 * 60 * 24
            )
  from ( select systimestamp - (systimestamp - 1) as interval_difference
           from dual )
```

Is there a more elegant method in SQL or PL/SQL?

Comment: :somewhere i have found this `
        select   (TRUNC(SYSDATE) + out.interv - TRUNC(SYSDATE)) * 86400
        from (select systimestamp -(systimestamp -1) as interv from dual )out`

Comment: since adding the return of the interval in seconds to a fixed precision number variable, the fractional part of the second is lost in the query mentioned in comments

Comment: Although it may not seem elegant, I still prefer this basic solution as it does not suffer from "ORA-01873: the leading precision of the interval is too small" that easily.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I hope this help:

```
zep@dev> select interval_difference
      2        ,sysdate + (interval_difference * 86400) - sysdate as fract_sec_difference
      3  from   (select systimestamp - (systimestamp - 1) as interval_difference
      4          from   dual)
      5 ;

INTERVAL_DIFFERENCE                                                             FRACT_SEC_DIFFERENCE
------------------------------------------------------------------------------- --------------------
+000000001 00:00:00.375000                                                                 86400,375
```

With your test:

```
zep@dev> select interval_difference
      2        ,abs(extract(second from interval_difference) +
      3        extract(minute from interval_difference) * 60 +
      4        extract(hour from interval_difference) * 60 * 60 +
      5        extract(day from interval_difference) * 60 * 60 * 24) as your_sec_difference
      6        ,sysdate + (interval_difference * 86400) - sysdate as fract_sec_difference
      7        ,round(sysdate + (interval_difference * 86400) - sysdate) as sec_difference
      8        ,round((sysdate + (interval_difference * 86400) - sysdate) * 1000) as millisec_difference
      9  from   (select systimestamp - (systimestamp - 1) as interval_difference
     10          from   dual)
     11  /

INTERVAL_DIFFERENCE                                                             YOUR_SEC_DIFFERENCE FRACT_SEC_DIFFERENCE SEC_DIFFERENCE MILLISEC_DIFFERENCE
------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ------------------- -------------------- -------------- -------------------
+000000001 00:00:00.515000                                                                86400,515            86400,515          86401            86400515

zep@dev>
```

Comment: I ended up explaining exactly why this works here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17413839/458741

Comment: This doesn't work for some values of interval_difference. For example:
    select interval_difference,
      sysdate + (interval_difference * 86400) - sysdate as fract_sec_difference
    from (
      select systimestamp - (systimestamp - 1/3) as interval_difference
      from dual
    );

Answer (score 33):

An easy way:

```
select extract(day from (ts1-ts2)*86400) from dual;
```

The idea is to convert the interval value into days by times 86400 (= 24*60*60).
Then extract the 'day' value which is actually second value we wanted.

Comment: I adapted this to use `extract(day from (ts1-ts2)*86400*1000) / 1000` to get millisecond precision.

Comment: This works only for small intervals - under 1000s. After that, you'll hit the wall with `ORA-01873: the leading precision of the interval is too small`

Comment: @ŠtefanOravec I did a quick test. The biggest interval I can get is 11574 days in Oracle 11.2.0.4 as below:

> select extract(day from (systimestamp - (systimestamp - 11574))*86400) seconds from dual;                                                          

   SECONDS
----------
 999993600

Comment: @ZhaopingLua there is some internal data type conversion magic apparently in your test case, as it fails with interval datatype - `select extract(day from (numtodsinterval(10, 'hour')) * 86400) from dual;` vs `select extract(day from (numtodsinterval(1000, 'second')) * 86400) from dual;` (Oracle 18cXE)

Comment: @ZhaopingLu better test with table and conversion from persisted value `create table test as select numtodsinterval(10, 'hour') as value from dual;
select extract(day from (value) * 86400)  from test;`

Answer (score 11):

I've found this to work. Apparently, if you do arithmetics with timestamps they are converted to some internal datatype that, when substracted from each other, returns the interval as a number.

Easy? Yes. Elegant? No. Gets the work done? Oh yeah.

```
SELECT ( (A + 0) - (B + 0) ) * 24 * 60 * 60 
FROM
(
   SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP A,
          SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '1' MINUTE B
   FROM DUAL
);
```

Comment: This only gives me whole seconds.

Comment: Oops, true. The question spefically asked for micro/milliseconds. This is an easy way to give whole seconds, though.

Comment: CAST(A AS DATE) is equivalent to (A+0)

Comment: arithmetics with timestamps is not the same as converting interval type value stored in table

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, I don't think that there is an alternative (or more elegant) way of calculating total seconds from an interval type in pl/sql. As [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20130624094947/http://www.timvasil.com/blog14/post/2008/12/22/Converting-an-Oracle-interval-to-total-seconds.aspx) mentions:

```
... unlike .NET, Oracle provides no simple equivalent to TimeSpan.TotalSeconds.
```

therefore extracting day, hour etc from the interval and multiplying them with corresponding values seems like the only way.

Answer (score 4):

Based on [zep's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10101114/458741), I wrapped things up into a function for your convenience:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION intervalToSeconds( 
     pMinuend TIMESTAMP , pSubtrahend TIMESTAMP ) RETURN NUMBER IS

vDifference INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND ; 

vSeconds NUMBER ;

BEGIN 

vDifference := pMinuend - pSubtrahend ;

SELECT EXTRACT( DAY    FROM vDifference ) * 86400
     + EXTRACT( HOUR   FROM vDifference ) *  3600
     + EXTRACT( MINUTE FROM vDifference ) *    60
     + EXTRACT( SECOND FROM vDifference )
  INTO
    vSeconds 
  FROM DUAL ;

  RETURN vSeconds ;

END intervalToSeconds ;
```

Comment: Thank you, but a function is far less efficient than SQL. You'll lose around a millisecond per record in the SQL/PL/SQL context switch alone. There's also no need to select from dual or to assign the result to a variable, you can return it directly. I'd write the same function like this: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/42d23/1. However, I'd like to emphasise that a function should not be used if at all possible.

Comment: Also, now I come to think about it the code is mine... I was asking if there's a better way of doing it! Welcome to Stack Overflow :-).

Answer (score 3):

Use following query:

```
select (cast(timestamp1 as date)-cast(timestamp2 as date))*24*60*60)
```

Comment: this cast will truncate millisecond part

Comment: moreover it will give wrong result if timestamps are in different time zones (e.g. if daylight saving changed in between)

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @Zhaoping Lu answer but directly extracting seconds instead of getting them from the number of days.

```
SELECT extract(second from (end_date - start_date)) as "Seconds number"
FROM my_table
```

(worked on PostgresSQL 9.6.1)

Comment: in both PostgresSQL and Oracle this will extract seconds only from the interval without including minutes, hours or days in the returning value, so e.g. 1 hour interval would return 0

Answer (score 1):

For Postgresql, try

```
SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH from (end_date - start_date))
FROM my_table
```

The `EPOCH` gives the total seconds of the whole duration, as a floating-point value.

From https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT

> epoch For timestamp with time zone values, the number of seconds since
> 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC (negative for timestamps before that); for
> date and timestamp values, the nominal number of seconds since
> 1970-01-01 00:00:00, without regard to timezone or daylight-savings
> rules; **for interval values, the total number of seconds in the
> interval**

Answer (score 0):

A shorter method to convert timestamp to nanoseconds.

```
SELECT (EXTRACT(DAY FROM (
    SYSTIMESTAMP --Replace line with desired timestamp --Maximum value: TIMESTAMP '3871-04-29 10:39:59.999999999 UTC'
- TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC') * 24 * 60) * 60 + EXTRACT(SECOND FROM
    SYSTIMESTAMP --Replace line with desired timestamp
)) *  1000000000 AS NANOS FROM DUAL;

NANOS
1598434427263027000
```

A method to convert nanoseconds to timestamp.

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC' + numtodsinterval(
    1598434427263027000 --Replace line with desired nanoseconds
/ 1000000000, 'SECOND') AS TIMESTAMP FROM dual;

TIMESTAMP
26/08/20 09:33:47,263027000 UTC
```

As expected, above methods' results are not affected by time zones.

A shorter method to convert interval to nanoseconds.

```
SELECT (EXTRACT(DAY FROM (
    INTERVAL '+18500 09:33:47.263027' DAY(5) TO SECOND --Replace line with desired interval --Maximum value: INTERVAL '+694444 10:39:59.999999999' DAY(6) TO SECOND(9) or up to 3871 year
) * 24 * 60) * 60 + EXTRACT(SECOND FROM (
    INTERVAL '+18500 09:33:47.263027' DAY(5) TO SECOND --Replace line with desired interval
))) * 1000000000 AS NANOS FROM DUAL;

NANOS
1598434427263027000
```

A method to convert nanoseconds to interval.

```
SELECT numtodsinterval(
    1598434427263027000 --Replace line with desired nanoseconds
/ 1000000000, 'SECOND') AS INTERVAL FROM dual;

INTERVAL
+18500 09:33:47.263027
```

Replace 1000000000 by 1000, for example, if you'd like to work with milliseconds instead of nanoseconds.

I've tried some of posted methods, but a got the exception "ORA-01873: the leading precision of the interval is too smalll" when multiplying the interval by 86400, so I've decided do post the methods that works for me.

Answer (score -2):

SELECT to_char(ENDTIME,'yyyymmddhh24missff')-to_char(STARTTIME,'yyyymmddhh24missff') AS DUR
FROM DUAL;
yyyymmddhh24miss- WILL GIVE DURATION IN SEC
yyyymmddhh24mi DURATION IN MIN
yyyymmddhh24 - DURATION - HOURS
yyyymmdd DURATION IN DAYS

Comment: Please format the code and explain the answer you posted.