# ORA-01873: the leading precision of the interval is too smalll

Tags: sql, oracle

I am getting an ORA-01873 "leading precision of the interval is too small" error from this statement and can't figure out why:

The `v_not_auto_bl_num` is declared as `VARCHAR2(1000)`.

What is causing the error?

Comment: what is your data type on NOT_AUTO_GTT

Answer (score 1):

In the code you originally posted you are doing:

```
ABS( EXTRACT(DAY FROM (TO_TIMESTAMP(DHS.ASSIGNMENT_IODT,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS.FF')
  - TO_TIMESTAMP(DHS.COMPLETED_IODT,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS.FF')) *86400*1000) / 1000)
```

The relevant part is this:

```
(TO_TIMESTAMP(DHS.ASSIGNMENT_IODT,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS.FF')
  - TO_TIMESTAMP(DHS.COMPLETED_IODT,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS.FF')) *86400*1000
```

If you subtract two timestamps you get an interval data type, not a number; e.g. if your table columns were, say, '20170419065416' and '20170419000000' then subtracting them would generate:

```
(TO_TIMESTAMP(DHS.A
-------------------
+00 06:54:16.000000
```

If you multiply that by 86400*1000 you exceed the precision of the interval data type. I chose that value because one second less is OK:

```
with dhs (assignment_iodt, completed_iodt) as (
  select '20170419065415', '20170419000000' from dual
)
select (TO_TIMESTAMP(DHS.ASSIGNMENT_IODT,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS.FF')
    - TO_TIMESTAMP(DHS.COMPLETED_IODT,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS.FF')) as original,
  (TO_TIMESTAMP(DHS.ASSIGNMENT_IODT,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS.FF')
    - TO_TIMESTAMP(DHS.COMPLETED_IODT,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS.FF')) *86400*1000 as multiplied
from dhs;

ORIGINAL            MULTIPLIED               
------------------- -------------------------
+00 06:54:15.000000 +24855000 00:00:00.000000
```

Once second more (or, in fact, anything beyond 20170419065415.134814814, or any pair of values with the actual interval above 06:54:15.134814814) will error as the multiplied interval is out of range for the data type.

What's actually happening under the hood is unclear; using a smaller multiplier also causes the issues once you cross that raw interval size limit.

Anyway, you seem to be trying to get the number of while seconds, which you can do by extracting each time element and multiplying them individually:

```
select abs(
    (extract(day from diff) * 86400)
      + (extract (hour from diff) * 3600)
      + (extract (minute from diff) * 60)
      + trunc(extract (second from diff))
  ) as c_f_previous_time
from (
  select to_timestamp(dhs.assignment_iodt,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS.FF')
    - to_timestamp(dhs.completed_iodt,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS.FF') as diff
  from dhs
);
```

I've put the timestamp subtraction in an inline view just so it doesn't have to be repeated within each extract call. You can put the rest of your original query inside that inline view (or a CTE) too.

Incidentally, the `abs()` implies you can have rows in your table where the completed date is earlier than the assignment; or just that you didn't notice you're doing the subtraction the wrong way round. If you data cannot have completed before assigned then you can swap the terms over and lose the `abs()`; I'd probably swap the terms anyway just to make it look more logical.

Answer (score 0):

### first try this:

```
create table test_table as
SELECT ACT_BL.BL_NUM,
      ABS( EXTRACT(DAY FROM (TO_TIMESTAMP(DHS.ASSIGNMENT_IODT,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS.FF') - TO_TIMESTAMP(DHS.COMPLETED_IODT,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS.FF')) *86400*1000) / 1000) AS C_F_PREVIOUS_TIME
    FROM DOCI_ACTIVITY ACT ,
      DOCI_ACTIVITY_RELATED_BL ACT_BL ,
      DSH_ACTIVITY DHS
    WHERE ACTIVITY_TYPE   IN ('BlCodingAndFormatting','BlCreationFromESI')
    AND ACT.ACTIVITY_ID    =ACT_BL.ACTIVITY_ID
    AND ACT_BL.ACTIVITY_ID = DHS.ACTIVITY_ID
    AND ACT_BL.BL_NUM      = v_not_auto_bl_num;
```

then check the **test_table**  columns type(*BL_NUM and C_F_PREVIOUS_TIME*)

after that you apply that column types to your table

Comment: This is doing the same interval calculation, so it will get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the exception is raised when you multiply an interval by 86400.

As I've posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63596939/6866545) you could use the following shorter method to convert interval to milliseconds.

```
SELECT ROUND((EXTRACT(DAY FROM (
    TO_TIMESTAMP(DHS.ASSIGNMENT_IODT,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS.FF') - TO_TIMESTAMP(DHS.COMPLETED_IODT ,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS.FF')
) * 24 * 60) * 60 + EXTRACT(SECOND FROM (
    TO_TIMESTAMP(DHS.ASSIGNMENT_IODT,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS.FF') - TO_TIMESTAMP(DHS.COMPLETED_IODT ,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS.FF')
))) * 1000) AS MILLIS FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score -1):

Your numeric number appears to be too large for the ABS function to handle. The biggest value you can pass to ABS() as the number is 2^31-1:

Comment: what do you mean 2^31-1?

Comment: The `abs()` function has no such restriction. The only limit is the precision Oracle supports for the number data type, which is way higher than that. The error is happening in the interval multiplication, before it gets to this function call.