# Timestamp difference in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to know what is the time difference between two timestamp:

```
CREATE TABLE HELLO(
    START_ID TIMESTAMP,
    END_ID TIMESTAMP
    );
    
INSERT INTO HELLO (START_ID,END_ID) VALUES (TIMESTAMP '2020-01-01 00:00:01',TIMESTAMP '2020-02-01 10:10:10');
```

I supposed to use:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF (SECOND , START_ID , END_ID)
FROM HELLO
```

But Oracle gives me error: ORA-00904: "TIMESTAMPDIFF": invalid identifier. What should I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extracting the total number of seconds from an interval data-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10092032/extracting-the-total-number-of-seconds-from-an-interval-data-type)

Answer (score 2):

Since your data types are `TIMESTAMP` and you could have fractional seconds then you can either:

Subtract one timestamp from another to give an `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` difference (and will account for differences in time zones, if your timestamps have them) and extract the component parts:

```sql
SELECT   EXTRACT( DAY    FROM difference ) * 24 * 60 * 60
       + EXTRACT( HOUR   FROM difference ) *      60 * 60
       + EXTRACT( MINUTE FROM difference ) *           60
       + EXTRACT( SECOND FROM difference )
           AS difference
FROM   (
  SELECT end_id - start_id as difference
  FROM   hello
);
```

or, convert the values to `DATE` data types by truncating to the previous minute (which would discard any time zone information, if there was any) and then add the difference in seconds extracted from the timestamps:

```sql
SELECT ( TRUNC( end_id, 'MI' ) - TRUNC( start_id, 'MI' ) ) * 24 * 60 * 60
       + EXTRACT( SECOND FROM end_id )
       - EXTRACT( SECOND FROM start_id ) as difference
FROM   hello;
```

*(Note: if you naively use `CAST` to convert to a `DATE` then you will lose the fractional seconds on both timestamps and may get the wrong answer.)*

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE HELLO(
    START_ID TIMESTAMP,
    END_ID TIMESTAMP
);

INSERT INTO HELLO (
  START_ID,END_ID
) VALUES (
  TIMESTAMP '2020-01-01 00:00:01',TIMESTAMP '2020-02-01 10:10:10'
);
INSERT INTO HELLO (
  START_ID,END_ID
) VALUES (
  TIMESTAMP '2020-01-01 01:23:45.99999',TIMESTAMP '2020-01-01 01:23:46.00001'
);
```

Outputs:

> ```
> | DIFFERENCE |
> | ---------: |
> |    2715009 |
> |     .00002 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f84f30267d81500a053eba75f7faddba)*

Answer (score 0):

If you subtract one timestamp from another then you will find the `INTERVAL` and not the `number`.

If you really want the number of seconds then you can cast `timestamp` to `date` and then subtract it from another as follows:

```
SQL> SELECT (CAST(END_ID AS DATE) - CAST(START_ID AS DATE))*24*60*60 AS NUM_OF_SECONDS
  2    FROM HELLO;

NUM_OF_SECONDS
--------------
       2715009

SQL>
```

Comment: Yes, make sense. Suppose the start_id and the end_id is in hours, I mean, the start_id will be mainly 00:00:00 and the end_id something like 02:10:10 (Is a movie that lasts more or less 2 hours), how can I create a table with that and make a select with the difference in hours for example?

Comment: I am unsure what you are asking but Oracle dates consist of date and time. If you want a number of hours between two dates then you can multiply 24 with a difference between those two dates.

Comment: This gives the wrong answer when the timestamps have fractional seconds. I.e. `START_ID` and `END_ID` of `2020-01-01 01:23:45.9` and `2020-01-01 01:23:46.1` then the difference should be `0.2` but this outputs `1`.

Comment: Yes, It will not consider the fractional part. I agree @MT0

Comment: I'm not sure if I have to use date, because I want to know how long has the user been watching the movie. For example, if the user started at 00:00:00 of the movie and the user leaves at 01:10:00, I want to know that the user has watched 1 hour and 10 minutes of the movie.

Comment: @JiakaiDong In Oracle a `DATE` data type always has year, month, day, hour, minute and second components. A `TIMESTAMP` data type always has the same components plus can have fractional seconds (or can have a time zone).

Comment: @JiakaiDong I can see your requirement can be fulfilled with the smallest using as the second. I would suggest going for the `DATE` data type as operations on the `date` is much simpler and faster than the `TIMESTAMP` as can be seen from the MT)'s answer.

Comment: Depends on the requirement; if the OP wants to track start and end times to the frame of the movie then they want a `TIMESTAMP` to handle the fractional seconds. If they don't care about that granularity and just want to start and end at the nearest second then, yes, they probably should not use `TIMESTAMP` and should just use a `DATE` data type.